# Navigate to next view via Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Upon clicking on the button,  I want the user to navigate to another view. The following code works fine. However, I want to pass some values as well to the next screen. How am I suppose to do so ?

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueviewc" sender:self];

}
```

I also tried the following code and it works but the page navigates twice to the `MyV` viewcontroller. From `buttonClick` event and from `prepareForSegue` method. How can I prevent this ?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {



MyV *myv = (MyV*) segue.destinationViewController;


myv.navigationItem.title=@"Hey";

myv.arr=data;

}
```

Comment: Do you use a storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to perform the segue on your button click. If your button is triggering the segue, it will be performed automatically.

Remove the line -

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueviewc" sender:self];
```

from your method -

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
```

Also you must ideally check which segue is being performed, so that you can code according to the navigation being performed...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    if ([segue.idenifier isEqualToString:@"segueviewc"])
    {
            MyV *myv = (MyV*) segue.destinationViewController;
            myv.navigationItem.title=@"Hey";
            myv.arr=data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard check if the segue is directly connect from the button to the next view. If it does, you can simply delete the line.

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueviewc" sender:self];
```

i think the problem is, the segue is directly connected from the button action to the next view, and within the button action, you call the segue again!
cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueviewc"]) {
         MyV *myv = (MyV*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryboardID"];
         myv.navigationItem.title=@"Hey";
         myv.arr=data;
      }
 }
```

And you do not need IBAction method.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to trigger a segue:
1. You trigger it as an action from your button directly to the new view controller
2. You trigger the segue from one view controller to the second view controller.

I am guessing you are connecting it via 1st approach. Hence you should not trigger it from IBAction.